# Asp.net dynamically hide div's with for loop from code behind

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Imagine I have infinite divs with `id="div1"`, `id="div2"`, `id="div3"`, etc...
How can I hide them from code behind using a for loop? Something like:

```
for(i = 1; i <= DropDownList1.SelectedValue; i++)
{                    
    string div = "div" + i;
    div.Visible = false;
}
```

The above code doesn't work it's just to give you an idea of what I pretend to do.

Comment: did you try  idofdiv.Style["display"] = "none";

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: therefore you need a valid reference to the control which seems to be the core issue here. Once you have it you don't need to use style-display to hide it but you can use [`Control.Visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.100).aspx) as OP does. That has another advantage: the HTML for those divs is not even rendered.

Comment: what will be DropDownList1.SelectedValue ???

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: You're welcome! `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` seems to be an `int` since OP wants to loop until this number. Of course he needs to use `int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)` first. I guess this pseudo code should clarify his intentions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes! it's an int I get with Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the runat="server" to your divs.

I've use

the following method to find the controls that I got from http://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/

```
for(i = 1; i <= DropDownList1.SelectedValue; i++)
{                    
    var ctrl = FindControlRecursive(this.Page, string.Format("div{0}", i + 1))
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        ctrl .Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Method for finding controls:

```
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            if (root.ID == id)
            {
                return root;
            }

            foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
            {
                Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);

                if (t != null)
                {
                    return t;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: With some fixes I managed to get it done. Thank you for your answer and help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to access controls from code-behind, they need to be actual server controls. You can do that by placing the `runat="server"` attribute.

```
<div runat="server" id="div1"></div>
<div runat="server" id="div2"></div>
```

Then in code-behind you can access them like this:

```
int x = 0;
int.TryParse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, out x);

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    Control ctrl = Page.FindControl(string.Format("div{0}", i + 1));
    if (ctrl != null)
        ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

Obviously you can place this inside a loop and generate the id string to get all controls.

Beware that:

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.

More information: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've done what you suggested but what if you have to hide 50 divs? Will you manually apply that code 50 times? That's what I'm trying to avoid by using a loop.

Comment: @DLM as I said, you can easily place the code inside the loop to generate the id to find.

Comment: oh...sorry, I didn't read it carefully, but I can't get it to work.

If i try this... { Control ctrl = Page.FindControl("Labels1"); } retrieves ctrl null.


http://i.imgur.com/2kiKcIL.png

Comment: @DLM did you put the `runat="server"` attribute on your divs? Beware that if your divs are inside other server controls, the `FindControl` method will not find them. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: I had runat="server" attribute, the problem was related to your beware quote. Anyway, thank you for your replies!